# How to Get current location if logged in website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, geolocation

How to get the current location of a user if is logged in in my website and display it on a map?
Now i have figured out when a user login in my website via Facebook i can retrieve their friend list after acknowledge.
The part that i do not know how to do it is: when one of my friends is also logged in inside my website to show me his current location on the map.

I know that via Facebook is not possible to retrieve user current location.

Is there any other suggestion to archive this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GeoIP databases and web services](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing)

> MaxMind's GeoIP products enable you to identify the location,
>   organization, connection speed, and user type of your Internet
>   visitors. The GeoIP databases are among the most popular and accurate
>   IP geolocation databases available.

Also there is a **[HTML5 location services](http://html5demos.com/geo)** which you may find helpful